# Java Semaphore availablePermits with ThreadPool

Tags: java, java-8, semaphore

I'm learning semaphore in java using the tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/java-semaphore.

The first test in the tutorial (which is below one) is working fine.

```
@Test
public void givenLoginQueue_whenReachLimit_thenBlocked() {
    int slots = 10;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(slots);
    LoginQueueUsingSemaphore loginQueue = new LoginQueueUsingSemaphore(slots);
    IntStream.range(0, slots)
      .forEach(user -> executorService.execute(loginQueue::tryLogin));
    executorService.shutdown();
 
    assertEquals(0, loginQueue.availableSlots());
    assertFalse(loginQueue.tryLogin());
}
```

If I comment the line `executorService.shutdown();` in the above test case snippet then the test fails with below error.

> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: 
> Expected :0
> Actual   :1
> <Click to see difference>
> at org.testng.AssertJUnit.fail(AssertJUnit.java:59)
> at org.testng.AssertJUnit.failNotEquals(AssertJUnit.java:364)
> at org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals(AssertJUnit.java:80)
> at org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals(AssertJUnit.java:245)
> at org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals(AssertJUnit.java:252)
> at LoginQueueSemaphoreTest.givenLoginQueue_whenReachLimit_thenBlocked(LoginQueueSemaphoreTest.java:24)
> ```

Once I remove the comment and enable the `executorService.shutdown();` the test works fine.

I couldn't understand how the test(Semaphore available permits) depends on the external thread pool. Also, how is 1 slot available when I didn't release any permits? Any brief explanation would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this consistent behavior, or do you sometimes get a different actual value? Try replacing `executorService.shutdown()` with `Thread.sleep(15_000)` - does the test pass in that case? This does indeed seem very strange, especially since `shutdown()` does not wait for submitted tasks to finish, but it might just be that the extra time it takes to also execute that call is just enough to make sure that the 10 threads can be spawned and perform their work (calling `tryLogin()`) before the `assertEquals()` is executed.

Comment: `shutdown() does not wait for submitted tasks to finish` This is false. shutdownNow() does not wait, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()

Comment: @shazin the documentation you link literally reads "This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that." for `shutdown()`. `shutdown()` will initiate orderly shutdown, i.e., let submitted task run to completion, but the call _itself_ does not block while that happens.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken - Your suggestion is working. The `executorService.execute` asynchronously runs the task. Adding Thread.sleep solved the problem. I would have accepted if you answered the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this consistent behavior, or do you sometimes get a different value for `Actual` (when omitting the `executorService.shutdown()` call)? If you occasionally see other values (say 2 or 3), this strongly suggests that this is all due to scheduling/timing.

Try replacing `executorService.shutdown()` with `Thread.sleep(15_000)`. Does the test pass if you make this change? If yes, then this indicates that what happens is that the extra time it takes to also execute the `shutdown()` call is just enough to make sure that the 10 threads can be spawned and perform their work (calling `tryLogin()` to decrement the `Semaphore`) *before* the `assertEquals()` call is executed. Note that, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()), `shutdown()` initiates an orderly shutdown of the `ExecutorService` in that it lets executing tasks run to completion, but *the call itself* does *not* block during that period. As a result, it seems like it is purely by chance that the time it takes to execute `shutdown()` is just enough to allow the other threads to terminate. As such, this is not a very good test as that behavior may vary across different machines. Instead, the test should have called `shutdown()` *followed by* `awaitTermination()` (or alternatively used a `CountDownLatch` decremented by the workers to block the main thread) to ensure that the `assertEquals()` call is not executed until *after* all the worker threads have terminated.

Comment: A simpler solution would be `executorService.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(slots, loginQueue::tryLogin));` which submits the desired number of jobs and then waits for their completion. But of course, it’s not feasible for a textbook trying to show as many different features as possible…